# Struct is unexpected size

Tags: c, struct, compiler-optimization

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  uint8_t d;
  uint8_t data[2];
} struct1;

typedef struct {
  uint16_t a;
  uint8_t d;
  uint8_t data[2];
} struct2;

int main(void) {
  printf("%u\n", sizeof(struct1));
  printf("%u\n", sizeof(struct2));
  return 0;
}
```

I would expect `struct1` to have a size of 3, and `struct2` to have a size of 5. However when I run this code, I see that `struct2` has a size of 6.

```
>./main
3
6
```

I guess the compiler is doing some sort of padding here, but why is struct 1 allowed to have an odd byte size but not struct 2?

Comment: Your architecture might not allow reading `uint16_t` at unaligned addresses.

Comment: BTW: The correct format specifier for ptinting `size_t` is `%zu´, not `%u`